# Esper EPL pattern fires only once

Tags: esper

I am trying to create a pattern in EPL, but i do not get why it gets matched only one. Here is what I did on the web page [Esper EPL online](https://esper-epl-tryout.appspot.com/epltryout/mainform.html). The EPL I input in the left textbox is:

```
create schema StockTick(signature string, source string, destination string, action string);
@Name('Monitor') select * from StockTick;
@Name('Out') select * from pattern [A=StockTick -> B=StockTick(B.source = A.source and B.destination = A.destination and B.action='block') where timer:within(2 seconds)];
```

and the events I input in the middle textbox are:

```
StockTick={signature='sig1', source ='s1', destination ='d1'}
t=t.plus(0.4 seconds)

StockTick={source ='s1', destination ='d1', action='block'}
t=t.plus(0.4 seconds)

StockTick={signature='sig2', source ='s2', destination ='d2'}
t=t.plus(0.4 seconds)

StockTick={source ='s2', destination ='d2', action='block'}
t=t.plus(0.4 seconds)
```

The output I get in the right box:

```
At: 2001-01-01 08:00:00.000
Statement: Monitor
Insert
StockTick={signature='sig1', source='s1', destination='d1', action=(null)}

At: 2001-01-01 08:00:00.400
Statement: Monitor
Insert
StockTick={signature=(null), source='s1', destination='d1', action='block'}
Statement: Out
Insert
stmt2_pat_0_1={A={StockTick={signature='sig1', source='s1', destination='d1', action=(null)}}, B={StockTick={signature=(null), source='s1', destination='d1', action='block'}}}

At: 2001-01-01 08:00:00.800
Statement: Monitor
Insert
StockTick={signature='sig2', source='s2', destination='d2', action=(null)}
At: 2001-01-01 08:00:01.200
Statement: Monitor
Insert
StockTick={signature=(null), source='s2', destination='d2', action='block'}
```

So:

- after 0 seconds, the Monitor statement gets fired (fine!)
- after 0.4 seconds, the Monitor statement gets fired again (fine!)
- after 0.4 seconds, the Out statement gets fired (fine!)
- after 0.8 seconds, the Monitor statement gets fired again (fine!)
- after 1.2 seconds, the Monitor statement gets fired again (fine!)

What I do not understand is why after 1.2 seconds I do not get fired the Out statement again, as I would expect.

Please note that if I try the first two inserts alone and the second two inserts alone, in both cases I have the Monitor statement fired twice and the Out statement fired once. The problem arises when I concatenate the four insert statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [another forum](https://community.rsa.com/thread/204454), I managed to solve the problem. I missed the `every` keyword in defining the pattern, so, after updating the rule as follows:

```
@Name('Out') select * from pattern [every A=StockTick -> B=StockTick(B.source = A.source and B.destination = A.destination and B.action='block')];
```

it worked like a charm:

```
At: 2001-01-01 08:00:00.000
Statement: Monitor
Insert
StockTick={signature='sig1', source='s1', destination='d1', action=(null)}

At: 2001-01-01 08:00:00.400
Statement: Monitor
Insert
StockTick={signature=(null), source='s1', destination='d1', action='block'}
Statement: Out
Insert
stmt2_pat_0_0={A={StockTick={signature='sig1', source='s1', destination='d1', action=(null)}}, B={StockTick={signature=(null), source='s1', destination='d1', action='block'}}}

At: 2001-01-01 08:00:00.800
Statement: Monitor
Insert
StockTick={signature='sig2', source='s2', destination='d2', action=(null)}

At: 2001-01-01 08:00:01.200
Statement: Monitor
Insert
StockTick={signature=(null), source='s2', destination='d2', action='block'}
Statement: Out
Insert
stmt2_pat_0_0={A={StockTick={signature='sig2', source='s2', destination='d2', action=(null)}}, B={StockTick={signature=(null), source='s2', destination='d2', action='block'}}}
```